# php remove image extention convert to string first or just array

Tags: php

`$d` is an array `Array ( [0] => image1.jpg [1] => image3.jpg [2] => image2.jpg [3] => stores1.jpg [4] => stores2.jpg [5] => stores2.jpg [6] => stores3.jpg [7] => stores4.jpg [8] => design1.jpg [9] => design2.jpg ) ;`

I can get all file names as string

```
$d = '';
foreach($d as $value){
     $d .= '"'.$value.'",';
}
echo $d;
```

I got

```
"image1.jpg","image3.jpg","image2.jpg","stores1.jpg","stores2.jpg","stores2.jpg","stores3.jpg","stores4.jpg","design1.jpg","design2.jpg",
```

How can remove all .jpg to have

```
"image1","image3","image2","stores1","stores2","stores2","stores3","stores4","design1","design2",
```

I am wondering if I need to remove all .jpg before converting to string or after converting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) would help

```
array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = basename($v,'.jpg');});
```

###The code

```
<?php
$arr=array("image1.jpg","image3.jpg","image2.jpg","stores1.jpg","stores2.jpg","stores2.jpg","stores3.jpg","stores4.jpg","design1.jpg","design2.jpg");
array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = basename($v,'.jpg');});
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => image1
    [1] => image3
    [2] => image2
    [3] => stores1
    [4] => stores2
    [5] => stores2
    [6] => stores3
    [7] => stores4
    [8] => design1
    [9] => design2
)
```

**`EDIT :`**

> if I just want to keep the first 4 letters 'imag', 'stor' what method
> should I use?

Replace the earlier `array_walk` with this new `array_walk`

```
array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = substr($v,0,4);});
```

Comment: if I just want to keep the first 4 letters 'imag', 'stor' what method should I use? THanks a lot for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace target file extensions with an empty string

```
function remove_extensions_from_array(array $files){

   $result = array();

   foreach($files as $file) {
      // Grab target extension
      $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      // Replace it with an empty string and push into $result array
      $result[] = str_replace(array('.', $extension), '', $file);
   }

   return $result;
}
```

This will work with nearly any extension (not only `.jpg`), since an extension isn't tightly-coupled

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use explode

```
$testarrays = array ('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg' );

foreach ($testarrays as $key=>$value){
    $temp = explode(".", $value);
    $filename[$key] = $temp[0];
}


print_r($filename);
```